# Unknown pentatomid from India

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug last year in August in Bharatpur, Rajasthan, India. The scale at the bottom of the picture is in mm and the size of the bug seem to be about 1.5 cm.

It looks a bit like Halyomorpha halys, but all the pictures of H. halys I've seen show white markings and sometimes more colour and not the dark markings as shown here.

[image: unkown pentatomid]

Comment: Oh, and it was feeding on the bird dropping shown in the upper left corner.

Comment: For me it does not look like `Halyomorpha halys` because as you said the white marking but also there are some white sections in the antennas (see [here](http://ephytia.inra.fr/fr/I/28801/23-Halyomorpha-halys-JSTR)). We have also this specie in Europe and considered as invasive.

Comment: Also the head is more squared on the `Halyomorpha halys` as shown in this picture from the [same site](https://ephytia.inrae.fr/fr/I/44827/4-Halyomorpha-halys-adulte), yours has a triangle/sharp head.